# Eclipse - Export/Save Search Results

Tags: eclipse, search

Eclipse's Search results view is quite handy with its tree-like structure. Is there any way to export these results to a readable text format or save them to a file for later use?

I've tried using copy & paste but the resulting text format is far from readable.

Comment: I believe the most recent answer (about the CDT plugin, which works) should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No I don't think there is a possibility to export the results yet. (Update: [Now there's a suitable plugin available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138046/2436175)). But you should be able to use the eclipse search framework programmatically an export the entries by yourself.

I did not test the following snipped but implemeted a custom search that way once (using the [RetrieverAction class](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/eclipse/search2/internal/ui/text2/RetrieverAction.java.html)). You should be able to listen to search result changes without the action as well:

```
TextSearchQueryProvider provider= TextSearchQueryProvider.getPreferred();

// your input (you'll have to implement that one I think...)
TextSearchInput input = new TextSearchQueryProvider.TextSearchInput();

ISearchQuery query= provider.createQuery(input);
ISearchResult result = query.getSearchResult();
result.addListener(new ISearchResultListener() {

    public void searchResultChanged(SearchResultEvent e) {
        // -> export result
    }
});

// run the query
NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(query);
```

Again: I did not test that at all and don't know if there is a better approach as well..

Comment: This may help you as well: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_a_Search_dialog%3F

Answer (score 18):

You can change the mode from tree to list by click 'upper-right corner triangle' ->'show in list', then just copy all the files in the list , it will be a perfect list of search result

Comment: Sadly, the results in 'Show as List' lack many details, like line number and full path to file.

Comment: This isn't true... list view only gives the matching files, and count of matches, (like grep -c) but, doesn't give the actual matched lines.

Answer (score 15):

I'm using [Eclipse Search CSV Export](https://sourceforge.net/projects/csv-export/).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)

Comment: Now that is nice, worked in 2023-03. The link, however, is not accessible. But you can download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/csv-export/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
As soon as the search results complete loading they open up all in the tree view, then click on one nd select all using (Ctrl+A), copy and paste in notepad. it won't be as pretty as in eclipse but you will be having all the files with line numbers.