# How to save search results in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I had to do a search for a string over the CVS repository.
It had yeilded me nearly 4000 search results.

Is there a way to save these results from eclipse into a text file such that " the format and font is saved"?

I have tried to save the results by copy paste into notepad/word document.
But the results got saved with the format lost ( i.e the hierarchial view is lost and i have got simple plain text).

Could someone suggest a plugin/tool that would help me?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse - Export/Save Search Results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339088/eclipse-export-save-search-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the short answer is no, there is no way to do it that provides all the details.  Based on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339088/eclipse-export-save-search-results), you can click the little upside-down triangle and choose "Show as List" and then you can copy and paste the list to your favorite text editor, but it will not have line numbers or line snippets.

Comment: Yepp, looks like there is no way. Thanks for the reply anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to mark this question as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339088/eclipse-export-save-search-results).

Anyway, the updated answer is that now it exists a suitable plugin for saving Eclipse search results, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138046/2436175).