# In Eclipse, is there a way to "bookmark all" file-search findings?

Tags: eclipse, search, eclipse-plugin

In the Find/Search Dialogs of Textpad and also in Visual Studio, there is a button to "Bookmark all" file-search findings. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse, by customizing it, or is there another plugin?

I know from searching here that there is an [Eclipse Bookmarks plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20150403060958/http://www.etc.to/eclipse_bookmarks_plugin). But it does not what I want, because it only adds single bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not thyat I know of.
An alternative would be to provide some way to save the result of a search, but if you look at answers like:

- [Eclipse - Export/Save Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339088/eclipse-export-save-search-results)
- [How to save search results in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654489/how-to-save-search-results-in-eclipse)

Those answers don't leave much hope on that feature.

Finally, [bug 169252 "Store Previous Searches for Startup"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=169252) has been "assigned" since 2006 (while [bug 277446 "remember search results between eclipse executions"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=277446) is a duplicate of bug 169252).