# How to save results to the text of eclipse search?

Tags: eclipse, search

I want to search for specific regex and save searched lines to the file.

is there any solution available to achive this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342414 helps?

Comment: @KiranSubbaraman : This could help when I am writing eclipse plugin or something like that. but I am a simple eclipse user & I want to save my search result from result view.